# multi column dropdownlist using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to bind data(For ex: Employee name, Employee ID from Employee) to a dropdownlist and the data should be displayed in dropdownlist as two columns. I don't want to separate this columns by using any special characters like | or '-'. I want to display them as different columns in a dropdownlist.

How can i achieve this using .net and the data i need to retrieve using SQL server 2008.

Comment: Using Winforms or WPF? You'll have more luck with WPF since it provides controls that can display data, not just a string.

Comment: cannot be done, dropdown list <input type="select"> is a single list of elements - not a 2x2 list of elements. This is the HTML specification. You could always have two dropdown lists, and style them so they look like a single one (right next to each other, no padding). But beyond that youre out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a WPF ComboBox? If so, use the ItemTemplate:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Width="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Client" SelectedItem="{Binding Client}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Configure as required -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Of course you have to format your StackPanel (or Grid, ...) to get desired output.

Comment: No problem, asp.net tag added to question.

Answer (score 0):

I used this post and basically created my own.  It works pretty good except that I can't get the drop down icon to display right away.  It only displays when you hover over the control.  I'm sure I could do it using css and an icon, but wish it was built in.

http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2008/07/31/developing-multicolumn-dropdowndropdownlist-with-aspnet-the-gridview-and-the-ajax-control-toolkit/